# Disable a form field in LotusScript or using Input Enabled formula

Tags: formula, lotus-notes, lotus-domino, lotusscript, domino-designer-eclipse

Using Domino Designer 8.5. If I have a form with a radio button field, is it possible to disable that field in LotusScript, possibly in the Postopen even of the form?

The only way I can, so far, see of achieving this is by using the Input Enabled formula of the field itself, but I am struggling to understand when this is triggered... if I try to put a @StatusBar or @Prompt formula call in there as well then there is never any notification of Input Enabled being triggered.

If Input Enabled is the way to achieve this, not LotusScript, then is there a way I can have **a)** a formula that sets the Input Enabled condition *plus* **b)** a way of getting some visual output, either to the Status Bar or a Message Box, to either just indicate the formula has been triggered or - even better - to let me know the value of some variable I'd like to check?

Answer (score 4):

The Input Enabled Formula is triggered on every refresh of the document (F9, Save, NotesUIDocument.Refresh, etc.), it can not contain any code "interacting" with the user.

But you could do something like this:

1. Create a Field "InputEnabled"
   The best way to have a "controlling" field is to make it "Computed for Display". That way it is not stored in the document. As a formula you simply enter `@ThisValue`, then it does not change its value by itself and can be set using LotusScript. If you want to have an "initial" value, then the formula would be: `@If( @ThisValue = "" ; "YES" ; @ThisValue )`
2. In the "Input enabled" Formula of your other field write the code:

   InputEnabled = "YES"
3. Fill the "InputEnabled"- Field using a LotusScript (NotesDocument.ReplaceItemValue( "InputInabled", "YES" ), or using a Formula directly in the field.

Like that you can easily "see" what the conditions are (in the field InputEnabled) and change it using formula or script.

Comment: Yes, I had got to the point of having a hidden field. I can set its Value to "YES" or "NO" in Designer, what I'd like to do is set it to "YES" or "NO" in LotusScript contained in the Postopen event. Is that possible - I haven't been able to do it via Call Source.FieldSetText as I am warned the document needs to be in edit mode and the document is being opened in view mode for the time-being... the user still needs to *see* that the specific field is disabled for editing at that point.

Comment: Have you tried Call Source.Document.ReplaceItemValue("InputEnabled", "NO")

Comment: Unfortunately, I've hit a snag with this. If I set the field to be visible, so I can see its contents, and give it a Value of "NO" in Designer. Then I run code in Postopen that - based on some logic - does this `Call Source.Document.ReplaceItemValue ("EnabledField","YES")` then I can see the value change in Source - Document - Items - EnabledField in the debugger Variables tab - it changes from **"NO"** to **"YES"** there... but as soon as I hit Continue in the debugger the form shows **"NO"** in the field (which I made visible just to check)!!!

Comment: Sorry, edited my comment above. I think I'm missing something. Happy to elaborate on what I'm seeing if needed.

Comment: P.S. - I did try a `Call Source.Refresh` after the call to `ReplaceItemValue` but it says "Document command is not available".

Comment: check that the enabledField is not computed, and more important when you test you must be in editmode ! (make CTRl+E)

Comment: I changed the now-visible control field to be "Computed for display" when I now go into the form I see **"YES"** where **"NO"** was previously. I made no other change. The radio button I wanted to be enabled is now enabled. If I click on the radio button, it signifies it has been clicked, then goes grey (disabled) and the visible control field has reverted back to **"NO"**. What happened there? I've also changed the **Value** of the control field to @ThisValue, as suggested, and that seems to work fully - but I don't understand why yet.

Comment: PLEASE: Try to understand what you do.... I gave you the examples, but now you need to understand what happens. This platform is not there to help you debug your "trial and error" code, but to help with concrete questions...

Comment: My apologies; your assistance is very much appreciated. I need to get my head around how this works so I can make an update to an existing system I'm not familiar with. If I have a control field which is Computed for display with a Value of `@If (@ThisValue = "";"NO";@ThisValue)` then I see "NO" in the field. All good. However, if I put the following line in `Postopen` - `Call Source.Document.ReplaceItemValue ("ControlField","YES")` I would expect to see the field on the form change to "YES" but it does not, it remains as "NO"; even though the value reported in the debugger **is** "YES".

Comment: The "secret" is simple: You cannot alter a document in read- mode. And in  "read mode" there is no need to change that property as it is only relevant in edit mode. Copy your code to "PostModeChange" to make sure, that after you change the document into edit mode the caluclation is done properly. Then you can also use a Source.Refresh to show your changes immediately. Refresh will fail in Read Mode

Comment: @TorstenLink - that makes sense to me, *but* I have seen this value change on my screen as we've progressed this thread. I thought that was the problem we'd got around by changing it to Compute for display and also using `ReplaceItemValue`. Right now, I've got a Compute for display control field that I cannot change the value of in `Postopen` - was I dreaming that it had changed before even though I'm doing 1, 2 and 3 mentioned in your answer above. Is there something else I need to add here or can it not be done in `Postopen`?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/79330/discussion-between-hippogriff-and-torsten-link).

Answer (score 0):

**Old school way** to Disabling the radio button field:

You will have to use the **Hide paragraph if formula is true". Define a field: *MyButEnabled* accorting to which you enable (show) or disable (hide) the field. for UI convience display a complementary line that only display the value of your radio button (you can also use a computed radio button but it's not very pretty).

In the post open set the appropriated value for the field *MyButEnabled*. Dont forget to call uidoc.RefreshHideFormulas method.

**The notes input enabled way**: (see also: http://www-01.ibm.com/support/docview.wss?uid=swg21173862)
the notes input enabled formula is (for example)

```
@if(MyButEnabled="Y" ; 1 ; 0)
```

When you form is openned, the formula is computed, if the result is 0 the field won't be editable, 1 will allow field to be edited.

If you change the value of MyButEnabled, then you need to make a UIdocument.refresh in order to change to be reflected in the UI.